# Rigged Shape Keys on Models With Mirror Modifier?

Tags: modeling, rigging, shape-keys, mirror-modifier

Sorry if this is a noob question, I'm very new to 3d modelling and animation.

I modelled a humanoid character with a mirror modifier.

I want to use a shape key to realistically animate the elbow when the forearm is rotated.

I created the shape key on the left side and used the left forearm bone as the driver.

The problem is, that if I rotate the left forearm, the shape key is also applied to the right elbow, even though the right forearm bone isn't moving.

Is there a way to use a separate driver for the right side? I don't want to apply the mirror modifier, as I will need to do some additional modelling later.

Comment: Don't do shape keys until you are done modeling, shape keys do not work for if the mesh is modified after they've been they are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

man, as far as I know you can't even apply the mirror modification, with shape keys ... what you can do is finish your model! then make the shape keys on one side and duplicate and use mirror shape keys.

Comment: That makes sense. Cheers!